# Best practice for unit testing if a method is called

Tags: unit-testing, phpunit

Imagine we have a simple controller with a method used to register a service. It should only be inserted into the DB/File-system when it doesn’t exits. (I know this is possible in SQL)

```
<?php
class ServiceController {

    protected $c;

    public function __construct($c){
        $this->c = $c;
    }

    public function register($name, $protocol, $type){
        $serviceMapper = $this->c['SerivceMapper'];
        $service =  new Service(); // entity
        $service->setName($name);
        $service->setProtocol($protocol);
        $service->setType($type);
        if (!$serviceMapper->exists($service)){
            $serviceMapper->insert($service);
    }
}
```

Now I want to test this controller. Especially if the `insert` method is called on the servicemapper. 
There are 2 test cases: when the service already exits and when it doesn't exists. 
I have find a way to test this, but it looks like it's a bad practice and that there is a better way for it.

```
class ServiceControllerTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    public function testRegisterWhenItExists(){
        $c = new Container();
        $c['ServiceMapper'] = $this->getMockBuilder('ServicedMapper')
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->getMock();


        $c['ServiceMapper']->expects($this->any())
           ->method('exists')
            ->will($this->returnValue(false));


        $c['BackendMapper']->expects($this->any())
            ->method('insert')
            ->will($this->returnCallback(function($entity){
                ServiceControllTest::insertExec = true;
        }));

        $serviceController = new ServiceController($c);
        $serviceController->register('foo', 'bar', 'foobar');

        $this->assertEquals(true, self::insertExec);

    }

    public function testRegisterWhenItDoesntExists(){
        // Almost the same as in the other test
    }
}
```

Is this the correct way to test this? Are there any better ways? Thanks :)

EDIT: I think I have found the correct way:

```
 public function testRegisterWhenItExists(){
        $c = new Container();
        $c['ServiceMapper'] = $this->getMockBuilder('ServicedMapper')
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->getMock();

        $service = new Service();
        $service->setName('foo');
        $service->setProtocol('bar');
        $service->setType('foobar');


        $c['ServiceMapper']->expects($this->any())
           ->method('exists')
           ->with($this->equalTo($service)) 
            ->will($this->returnValue(false));


        $c['BackendMapper']->expects($this->any())
            ->method('insert')
           ->with($this->equalTo($service));


        $serviceController = new ServiceController($c);
        $serviceController->register('foo', 'bar', 'foobar');


}
```

Is this the correct way, to test this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm almost sure I found the correct way to make sure a function is called on a mock.

```
// This will assert that the "exists" function can be called 0,1 or more times    
$c['ServiceMapper']->expects($this->any())
    ->method('exists')
    ->with($this->equalTo($service)) 
    ->will($this->returnValue(false));


// This will assert that the "exists" function can be called 0 times    
// when the "exists" method is called, the unit test will fail
$c['ServiceMapper']->expects($this->never())
    ->method('exists')
    ->with($this->equalTo($service)) 
    ->will($this->returnValue(false));
```

Full documentation is at http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/test-doubles.html#test-doubles.mock-objects.tables.matchers